# how to make a column not updatable in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

how to make a column not updatable in hibernate

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column( updatable=false )
```

The column mapped would not be updatable using HQL or via hibernate methods.

Comment: Thank you Si mo.. **It's working fine**, same logic i used in hibernate mapping file like 

 `<property name="xyz" update = "false"/>`